# Issue with torch.eq()

Tags: python, pytorch

I am comparing the outputs of my model with the answer tensor, but there is something wrong when I use `torch.eq()`.

The output (a) of my model is

```
a = tensor([[2.9925, 5.5364],
        [2.1770, 4.2641],
        [2.6148, 5.2682],
        [2.9802, 5.7929],
        [2.9113, 5.2646],
        [2.6978, 4.8034],
        [2.0447, 4.3377],
        [2.5878, 5.0370],
        [3.3953, 5.6000],
        [2.3221, 4.5645]])
```

and the tensor I'm comparing a to, b is as follows

```
b = tensor([[2.9925, 5.5364],
        [2.1770, 4.2641],
        [2.6148, 5.2682],
        [2.9802, 5.7929],
        [2.9113, 5.2646],
        [2.6978, 4.8034],
        [2.0447, 4.3377],
        [2.5878, 5.0370],
        [3.3953, 5.6000],
        [2.3221, 4.5645]])
```

It's exactly the same. However, when I use `torch.eq(a, b)`, I get

```
tensor([[ True,  True],
        [False,  True],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True, False],
        [ True,  True]])
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening??? I've been looking at this error for over an hour, and still cannot find the reason why this is happening.

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic operation is easy to produce small errors (which may not be reflected after formatting as strings). Instead of using `torch.eq` to compare two floating point tensors, use [`torch.allclose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.allclose.html) instead.